# PowerBI - Convert Date to the WeekNumber of the Month

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
    Date          WeekNum      Month   Year 
    5/2/2018      Week 1        May    2018
    6/1/2018      Week 1       June    2018
```

How would you get the WeekNum from the Date? 
The WeekNumber needs to be week number of the particular month and not the Year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to take the day of the month and divide by seven:

```
WeekNum = ROUNDUP(DIVIDE(DAY(TableName[Date]), 7), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next formula

`1 + WEEKNUM(usage_users[row_date]) - WEEKNUM(STARTOFMONTH(usage_users[row_date]))`

This gives you the number of the week.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to use STARTOFMONTH and WEEKNUM together:

Here is a good video explaining it also:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq5WOmo94_Q

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31337547)